# Entity Framework Constraints with Oracle DB

Tags: c#, database, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

pulling my hair out on this...I have a code-first entity model for oracle, and I am having problems getting around this foreign key issue:

"The property 'aidYearCode' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter. For collection properties the type must implement ICollection where T is a valid entity type."

Here are the relevant code snippets:

1) in "OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)":

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<INSTITUTIONAL>()
            .HasMany(e => e.applicantBudgetComponents)
            .WithRequired(e => e.institutional) // so this exists in APPLICANT_BUDGET_COMPONENTS: public virtual INSTITUTIONAL institutional { get; set; }
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.aidYrCode)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

2) the table APPLICANT_BUDGET_COMPONENTS with the foreign key has:

```
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [StringLength(4)]
        public string aidYrCode { get; set; }
```

3) lastly the INSTITUTIONAL table has the primary key:

```
    [Key]
    [StringLength(4)]
    public string aidYearCode { get; set; }
```

This was all generated by the Code-First wizard in VS2015, here is what I have tried:

- putting the annotation

  [ForeignKey("aidYrCode")] in 2)
- putting the annotation from oracle's schema in 2)

  [ForeignKey("FK1_RBRACMP_INV_ROBINST_CODE")]
- adding "Id" to Foreign Key Names so as to follow EF6 conventions.

it should be noted that APPLICANT_BUDGET_COMPONENTS has a composite primary key.

Comment: Does *this* code produce the exception message? Also, it would help to see more relevant parts of the classes. It seems that `APPLICANT_BUDGET_COMPONENTS` also has a property `aidYearCode`.

Comment: yes - this is the exact code

Comment: what else do you want to see? I cannot post all properties and fluent annotations (it would be huge) but i want to give you what you think might help :)

Comment: *'aidYearCode' cannot be configured as a navigation property* means that somewhere in your mappings you have setted `aidYearCode` as navigation property. For example, `modelBuilder.Entity<INSTITUTIONAL>().HasRequired(m => m.aidYearCode)`

Comment: I do not have .HasRequired anywhere in my model configuration; perhaps that is the problem? (I know I'm contradicting what you said but I'm out of things to try at this point)

Comment: .HasRequired is not an option when it cascades off of .WithRequired (see 1) in OP, so I'm looking at .Map now...

Comment: when all table and column remappings are removed (eg .HasColumnName(...) and ToTable(...) the error disappears!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the error message was spurious; the configuration of "aidYearcode" was correct, however, after digging deeper I found some missing model configurations in other tables (indirectly related to the ones mentioned here) and after inserting the proper fluent commands and attributes for those properties the "error" was resolved.